# How to set value to combobox with remote store in extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

What is the correct approach to be followed for setting value to a combobox in Extjs 4.2. Prior to Extjs 4.2, the combobox with remote store was set using the following piece of code.

```
var book= Ext.create('Test.model.Book', bookValues);
bookCombo.store.loadRawData([book]);
bookCombo.setValue(book.getId());
bookCombo.setRawValue(book.get('name'));
bookCombo.displayTplData = book.data;
bookCombo.fireEvent('change', bookCombo, book.getId());
```

But the above piece of code doesn't set the value of the remote combo correctly since 4.2.

Comment: How does it not set the value? The field remains empty? It shows the id instead of the name? Or does it work at first, and then lose the value when you expand the combo?

Comment: it used to work without the loadRawData line prior to 4.2 . I would like to know if after 4.2, we need to load the data and set value ? Whether this is the correct approach.

Comment: This is not an easy question, in fact... The usual approach is rather to wait for the combo store to be loaded before displaying it (see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17942315/1387519)). But yours is interesting too... How do you get the book model you're trying to load in the store? Is your combo store supposed to be loaded beforehand? Is it remote?

Comment: The store is remote and on edit of form, the value needs to be set from the data.

Answer (score 2):

this drove me crazy but finally I have a solution.

first you have to define a Model for the store and then you can set the value with a new model instance.

```
// model
      Ext.define('UserSearchFieldModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
          {name: 'user_id',  type: 'string'},
          {name: 'displayname', type: 'string'}
        ]
      });

// store
      UserSearchField_Store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'UserSearchFieldModel',
        remoteFilter: true,
        proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          url: '...',
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'userList'
          }
        }
      });

// field
    {
      itemId: 'userField',
      xtype: 'combo',
      queryMode: 'remote',
      hideTrigger: true,
      store: UserSearchField_Store,
      displayField: 'displayname',
      valueField: 'user_id'
    }

// set a initial value on load
    this.down('#userField').setValue(Ext.create('UserSearchFieldModel', {
      id: initialUser.id,
      displayname: initialUser.name
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think beneath loading the data `bookCombo.setValue(book.getId());` should be enough to set the value in your combo. The change event should fire automatically as soon as you set a value. And rest get called automatically after calling `setValue`

I think you mess it up by calling all these yourself.

Comment: Where do you see in the code of Ext JS that store loading is triggered by a `setValue` call on the combo? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox-method-setValue

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Not at all. The answer aims for the example code of the op and only means that he don't need to call anything after he has called `setVale()`... the loading happens here `bookCombo.store.loadRawData([book]);`