# Extjs 4.1 - How to wait all store in combo is loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a window include many combo with default autoload = false. I want to wait all combo in my window is loaded after that i will show window like

```
  var arrCombos = window.query('combo');
  Ext.each(arrCombos, function(combo){
     combo.getStore().load(); // load
  });

  WaitForFunction(arrCombos); // wait for loading done

  window.show(); // show my window
```

Here is my `WaitForFunction`

```
 function WaitForFunction(arrCombos) {
    var all = 1;
    Ext.each(arrCombos, function(combo){ 
        if (combo.store.isLoading()) {
            all = 0;
        }
    });
    if (all == 0){
        setTimeout(WaitForFunction(arrCombos), 100);
    }
}
```

But fail, that said `too much recursion`
How can i do that thank.

Comment: `setTimeout(WaitForFunction(arrCombos), 100)` is calling `WaitForFunction` immediately and passing the return value to `setTimeout`. What you meant was: `setTimeout(function() { WaitForFunction(arrCombos) }, 100)`. I think your code would have worked this way... But sra's approach based on events and a counter is better because it won't wait any unneeded ms.

Comment: @rixo yeah thank u. My code run but it's not working well:) i using sra 's code and it's well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty but something like this should work:

```
var arrCombos = window.query('combo'),
    storeCt = 0;

function checkState() {
  if(--storeCt == 0)
    window.show();
}

Ext.each(arrCombos, function (combo) {
  var store = combo.getStore();
  storeCt++;
  store.on('load', checkState, this, {single: true})
  store.load(); // load
});
```